# No-throw alternative to shared_from_this()

Tags: c++, c++11

Sometimes a class needs to obtain a `shared_ptr` to itself. One way to achieve this (when you know objects of the class will always live in `shared_ptr`s) is to derive from `std::enable_shared_from_this<SomeClass>` and call `shared_from_this()` as needed.

But one cavet with this approach that you can't call `shared_from_this()` from the destructor--since `enable_shared_from_this` uses a `weak_ptr` under the hood and since being in the destructor implies that the object's ref count is 0, a `bad_weak_ptr` exception will be thrown.

Now, I often find myself writing classes with nontrivial destructors that call into other functions that try to use `shared_from_this()`. For example:

```
~SomeClass::SomeClass()
{
   f();
}

// f can also be called outside the context of the destructor
/* public */ void SomeClass::f()
{
   g();
   m_anotherObject.h(shared_from_this()); // want to skip this if shared_from_this() fails
   i();
}
```

As mentioned, `f` as written will throw a `bad_weak_ptr` exception when it is called from the destructor. I could simply swallow that exception and move on to `i()`, but this violates the idea that exceptions should only be thrown under exceptional circumstances, and makes debugging more difficult when your IDE is configured to warn you whenever an exception is thrown. I could also refactor the code in any number of different ways to prevent `h` from being called from the destructor, but that would add complexity, hurt readability, and seems like a lot of unnecessary hassle. Or I could add some sort of `bool m_inDestructor` member variable, but that would be hideous.

```
/* public */ void SomeClass::f()
{
   g();

   try
   {   
      m_anotherObject.h(shared_from_this());
   }
   catch(std::bad_weak_ptr&) {} // don't like; exceptions should be exceptional

   i();
}

/////////////////////

SomeClass::~SomeClass()
{
   f(true);
}

/* public */ void SomeClass::f()
{
   f(false);
}

// works, but adds complexity I feel like I shouldn't need
/* private */ void SomeClass::f(bool inDestructor)
{
   g();
   if(!inDestructor)
      m_anotherObject.h(shared_from_this());
   i();
}
```

So my question is: has anyone come up with a generally-applicable, *non-throwing* mechanism for determining whether `enable_shared_from_this` actually has a `shared_ptr` to provide?

Comment: Can you give a real-world example of why you need to create shared pointers in the destructor? This sounds like a design flaw to me.

Comment: @FerdinandBeyer I don't need to. What I want to do is call some function `f` that does something with `shared_from_this` if it is available and skips that step otherwise. In the case that triggered this question, `h` is an unsubscribe function where subscriptions are tracked using weak_ptrs, meaning the call to unsubscribe/h can be skipped if `f` is called from the destructor, but must go through otherwise.

Comment: I guess the problem to me is that the only case where this'll come up is if you are trying to get a shared pointer from the current instance during clean up...the only reason I could see that this would be necessary is if you have a helper class/function that takes in the shared pointer to do so. By definition, the object being passed in should be being destroyed, or the object being created should put the class into a destroyed state. That means that the helper should either be private, or take a temprorary reference (`h(SomeClass& class)` rather than `h(SharedPtr<SomeClass> class)`).

Comment: @FerdinandBeyer But if that still troubles you, consider the case of a `SomeClass` object that may or may not exist in a `shared_ptr`, and wants to call `SomeOtherClass::f(std::shared_ptr<SomeClass>)` if it's possible and `SomeOtherClass::f(SomeClass*)` if it's not.

Comment: To expand, you should only take in a SharedPtr if you need to take ownership of the class. If you don't, rely on someone elses shared pointer, take in the reference. `h` should take a reference because it doesn't need to own the instance, because the reference it points to will still exist after it has completed.

Comment: @dlf There is no way to detect if it is safe to call `shared_from_this` and you should not need it.  If `f()` needs `shared_from_this` then you cannot call it from the destructor.  Period.  If you need some kind of clean-up that is required both in `f()` and the destructor, put it in another function.  This seems what `g()` and `h()` do, so call these instead of `f()` from the destructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to do this, you can just re-implement the `shared_from_this` idiom yourself, except have it return a null `shared_ptr` when appropriate.

To do this you add a `weak_ptr<SomeClass>` to `SomeClass` as a data member:

```
class SomeClass
{
    std::weak_ptr<SomeClass> weak_ptr_;
```

In your factory function, initialize the `weak_ptr`:

```
static std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> create()
{
    std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> p(new SomeClass);
    p->weak_ptr_ = p;
    return p;
}
```

And then write `shared_from_this` to do what you want:

```
std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> shared_from_this() {return weak_ptr_.lock();}
```

Now as long as `f()` can deal with an empty `shared_ptr` (and as long as you control all construction via your factory function), you're golden.

Comment: This is in fact exactly what I ended up doing (in every detail). I was going to write this answer up myself tomorrow if no one else did first. :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm moving this to an answer because I don't think I can explain it well in comments.

This is typically a good sign that you've overused shared pointers! You should ONLY use a shared pointer when you need to manage the lifetime of an object. Creating an instance of a shared pointer means that you are saying "I need to take some ownership of this object." This is great for interleaved data structures.

You should NOT use shared pointers (usually) in function calls that. A function call is typically in-out. The lifetime of the argument of a function call must last through the function call, but it is typically the caller's responsibility to ensure that, not the function.

Consider the following code:

```
class SomeClass;//implements enable_shared_from_this
int foo(shared_ptr<SomeClass> a);
int bar(shared_ptr<SomeClass> a);

int main()
{
   SomeClass c;
   foo(c.shared_from_this());
   bar(c.shared_from_this());
}
```

We KNOW c exists throughout the call: it cannot go out of scope. Requiring a shared pointer input limits who can use the class and adds overhead to the call, and gives us no more protections than we allready had. Whats worse is that it adds an error condition (shared_ptrs can still be null!).

The alternative is faster and more flexible:

```
class SomeClass;//implements enable_shared_from_this
int foo(SomeClass& a);
int bar(SomeClass& a);

int main()
{
   SomeClass c;
   foo(c);
   bar(c);
}
```

By taking in a reference, we've gurenteed that the instance must exist when passed in. And let the caller ensure that the reference lasts long enough. If c can be put in a destroyed/default state, than foo and bar will need to detect that anyway.

To your specific example, we should call

```
 int SomeClass::foo()
 {
    foo(*this);
 }
```

`this` must exists because we are calling the function. If SomeClass can have a destroyed state that you want to handle, than you should have a method (can be private or public) `bool is_destroyed() const` that can be checked in the call (though honestly I'd make that the caller's responsibility as well, and just say "You're trying to use a destroyed object? you're SOL").

edit 1: the exception for using a shared_ptr is that if there is a side effect of the function that DOES take ownership of the class (like launching a thread, setting a global, or returning a class with ownership) though if you implement enabel_shared_from_this I'd still take in a reference.

edit 2: SharedFromThis is a crutch (imho) because the following creates an error state:

```
 shared_ptr<SomeClass> ptr;
 {
    SomeClass a;
    ptr = a.shared_from_this();
 }
 ptr->foo();//because the parent went out of scope, it is destroyed anyway!
```

This is why the caller should just manage their own shared pointers.